# Xamarin.Forms - Bind a list of models to grid?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have this grid here:

```
<Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        </Grid>
```

What I am trying to do now is bind my this list I have to the grid, this is my code-behind:

```
List<TaxClass> taxes = new List<TaxClass>();

taxes.Add(new TaxClass { amount = 0.0, date = new DateTime() });
```

My question is how do I bind this list to the grid? I am trying to implement this add/remove feature.

Comment: A grid is a static layout, you can bind a list to it. You should look in to `ListView` or `CollectionView`

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to create a list view and set the item template as a grid. Something like the folowing:

```
    <ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="taxes">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                           <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                           <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <label text = "{binding amount}" grid.Column="0"/>
                        <label text = "{binding date }" grid.Column="1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
     </ListView>
```

In your code behind try `listView.ItemSource = taxes;`

Comment: Have a look here for more info - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/

Comment: I just tried your example, but nothing appears....am I missing something in the code behind?

Comment: Take a look at this to set the data source - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding

Answer (score 0):

There are many list control to presenting lists of data, especially long lists that require scrolling, for example ListView or Collectionview and other.

Ryan have provide some code about using ListView, If you still have some issue about ListView, you can take a look the sample at github, you can also take a look collectionview in this sample.

https://github.com/CherryBu/ListControl

Now, I provide some code about how to use Collectionview.

Firstly, CollectionView is introduced in Xamarin.Forms 4.0 pre-releases. CollectionView is a view for presenting lists of data using different layout specifications. It aims to provide a more flexible, and performant alternative to ListView.

You need to add the following code in Mainactivity.cs in android.

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //add this line
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetFlags("CollectionView_Experimental");
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
```

MainPage.xaml:

```
 <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding taxs}">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding amount}" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding date}" />
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```

MainPage.cs:

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public List<TaxClass> taxs { get; set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        taxs = new List<TaxClass>()
        {
            new TaxClass(){amount=12.01,date=DateTime.Parse("2019-01-01")},
             new TaxClass(){amount=13.01,date=DateTime.Parse("2019-01-01")},
              new TaxClass(){amount=14.01,date=DateTime.Parse("2019-01-01")},
               new TaxClass(){amount=15.01,date=DateTime.Parse("2019-01-01")},
                new TaxClass(){amount=16.01,date=DateTime.Parse("2019-01-01")}
        };
        this.BindingContext = this;
    }
}

public class TaxClass
{
    public double amount { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
}
```